# How Is it possible to create multiple logins in a web app in node.js express app for ex. admin & customer

Tags: node.js, authentication, oauth-2.0, passport.js, passport-google-oauth

Is it possible to create multiple logins in a  node.js express web app for example as an admin and customer using passport-google-oauth20 and perhaps other strategies ?

I am currently trying to build an e-commerce site which has a cms, i have a simple middleware function i am passing in the routes i want to protect and here is the function:

```
function ensureUserIsAuthenticated(req, res, next){ 
if(req.user){ next()}
else{return res.redirect('/login')
```

My goal is to restrict customers logging from from logging into the admin panel using google auth .

At the moment i have one google auth strategy i'm using. 
My question is do i have to create other strategies? how do i seperate the protection logic?

```
  /COOKIE SETUP
app.use(cookieSession({
    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60,
    keys: [COOKIE.COOKIE_KEYS]
}))

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id)
})


passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    User.findById(id).then(user => {
        done(null, user)
    }).catch(err => {
        if (err) throw err
    })
})

app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

// GOOGLE AUTHENTICATION
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: GOOGLE.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: GOOGLE.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: ' /auth/google/callback'
}, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {

    User.findOne({
        googleId: profile.id
    }).then(user => {
        if (user) {
            //Already a member.
            console.log('This User Exists')
            done(null, user)
        } else {
            //Register new member
            const user = new User({
                googleId: profile.id
            })
            user.save().then(user => {
                console.log('New Member Registered')
                done(null, user)
            }).catch(err => {
                if (err) throw err;
            })
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        if (err) throw err;
    })

}))


app.get('/login', (req, res, next) => {
    res.status(200).render('login')
})

app.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', {
    scope: ['profile', 'email']
}))

app.get('/auth/google/callback', passport.authenticate('google'),
    (req, res, next) => {
        res.redirect('/products');
    });


app.get('/api/current_user', isUserAuthenticated, (req, res, next) => {
    res.send(req.user);
})

app.use(ordersRoute);
app.use(productsRoute);

app.get('/logout', (req, res, next) => {
    req.logOut();
    console.log('Youve been logged out')
    res.redirect('/login')
})
```

OrdersRoutes Represent => Customer Routes
ProductRoutes Represent => Admin Routes

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am facing the same issue here my admin and customers also have different collections.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the role in input payload like 0 = admin and 1 = user,

So first you authenticate user, if authentication successful then based on role you can redirect it to admin and user page

Comment: Do you mind providing a dummy example, i am new to node and will help a lot. 
please note that admin and customers are different collections. i am connecting mongodb with mongoose.

Comment: Then you can create two different API for admin and user login